# Question about @login_required decorator and the redirect type

Tags: django, seo

By default, when using the `@login_required` decorator, Django performs a 302 (temporary) redirect when redirecting a non-authenticated user to the login page. I work in conjunction with an SEO company (I know nothing of the topic myself) and he insists that the 301 (permanent) redirect is essential to the work that he is doing.

Is there anyway to force Django to perform a 301 redirect while using the @login_required decorator?

Thanks again.

Comment: A 301 permanent redirect seems wrong here. Let's say you are protecting the URL `/secret-sauce/recipe`. If I an not logged in and hit `/secret-sauce/recipe`, then I should get redirected to the login page. *But* that page hasn't permanently moved; `/secret-sauce/recipe` is still a valid URL (and I should get redirected *back* to it once I log in). 301 is used when a page has moved and is invalid at the old URL.

Comment: Typical SEO expert: has no idea what he's talking about... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@login_required` decorator uses the `redirect_to_login` view, which returns a Django `HttpResponseRedirect` object to redirect the user to the login page. This object represents, as you mention, a 302 redirect. There is an alternative redirect object, the `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect`, though you would need to write your own decorator which uses this instead.

Writing your own decorator is, of course, possible. It would be bad practice though, in my opinion. Not least because it ties your app to a particular implementation of the authentication module, but also because a 302 redirect is actually the correct one to use in this case.

The fact is that the page has not "moved permanently". Instead, the user simply needs to authenticate himself/herself before accessing the same URL once again. For this reason, the redirect is not a permanent one, as the page has not actually "moved".

Comment: Btw, browsers usually cache those permanent redirects. So permenent_redirect in this situation could end up with a redirect loop in user's browser.

Answer (score 2):

- [`login_required`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L39) uses
- [`user_passes_test`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L12), which in turn calls
- [`redirect_to_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L101) in which the
- [`HttpResponseRedirect` is hard-wired](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L113).

So no, the type of redirect cannot be changed just using `login_required` alone. You could write your own login_required decorator to provide 301 redirect (although the use of this here is disputable).